# Correct terminology for polylines, their segments, knots, etc.

Tags: geometry, functions, approximation-theory, publishing, linear-approximation

Background: piecewise-linear continuous functions $f(x_k)=y_k$ with fixed set of knots $x_k$ with restrictions on the angles between adjacent segments.

The translator who dealt with my paper, introduced terminology that I don't like, i.e. (my variants are on the left):

- knots -> nodes
- adjacent segments -> neighboring links
- segment -> link
- polylines -> broken lines

Which one is better? How would you call piecewise-linear function, its segments, its knots? What are the most common namings for these?

NB: That's more about piecewise-linear *functions* than about polylines in the geometrical sense.

Comment: I would "knots" indeed replace by "nodes". For the rest, your terminology seems to be better that the translator's. That is, if your work is somehow related to numerical methods (as I understand from the tags).

Comment: @HandeBruijn Thanks a lot! Not exactly numerical methods, but pure approximation theory, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.